# "it is may happen" is correct or not?

Tags: word-usage

The meaning of **hope** given in Simple Wiktionary as

When someone hopes that something will happen, it means that they want it to happen and they think **it is may happen**.

This **it is may happen** is correct or not? I think "it may happen" is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It is may happen" is not correct.  "It may happen" is correct.  The "is" suggests "now", as in "Bob is hungry", but even given that, "is may" makes no sense.

Even "It may happen" is pretty neutral: is says "it may, or it may not".

I would suggest going with a more reliable dictionary - wiki entries are edited (changed) by anyone, whether they have expertise or not.

Here's one of several dictionaries:  [Collins Online Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english)

Some might say "Hopefully, it will happen", but grammar purists complain that "hopefully", being an adverb, doesn't qualify a verb in that use.  I don't object.  In spoken English, very few people will call that an error.

If you want to be really informal: "I sure hope it happens".

Answer (score 1):

It is a mistake in http://simple.wiktionary.org, and I will correct it.

Comment: Corrected in Simple wiktionary.